# How to update data in table within same id but different index

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  ticket_id   hold_time   unhold_time hold_comment    unhold_comment  dependency  statu
63  354843  6/16/2017 11:20:34 AM   6/16/2017 12:39:48 PM   a   Unhold done HR & Admin  Unhold
64  354843  6/16/2017 11:21:28 AM       a       HR & Admin  Hold
65  354843  6/16/2017 11:21:41 AM       vv      HR & Admin  Hold
```

I want to update data in last row (65) or dynamically last index. What is the query for mysql.

I use (where ticket_id= 354843) id is autoincrement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
UPDATE table
    SET ticket_id = 666
ORDER BY hold_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think you want `where ticket_id =  354843` as well, but the idea is correct.

Comment: Right! I've missed this id :D

Comment: Working fine...Thanks